# Does HTML allow for embedded encoding of images by stream?

Tags: html, image

Example:

```
<div id="sampleimage">

***Stream or Serialize JPEG Image from Server Here w/o Sending another Request***

</div>
```

So basically, send everything in a single response.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In some browsers (in FF, Chrome, and apparently IE8) you can use the [data URL scheme](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2397.txt) to embed an image file in HTML.

It looks something like this (taken from the RFC):

```
<IMG
   SRC="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhMAAwAPAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAMAAw
   AAAC8IyPqcvt3wCcDkiLc7C0qwyGHhSWpjQu5yqmCYsapyuvUUlvONmOZtfzgFz
   ByTB10QgxOR0TqBQejhRNzOfkVJ+5YiUqrXF5Y5lKh/DeuNcP5yLWGsEbtLiOSp
   a/TPg7JpJHxyendzWTBfX0cxOnKPjgBzi4diinWGdkF8kjdfnycQZXZeYGejmJl
   ZeGl9i2icVqaNVailT6F5iJ90m6mvuTS4OK05M0vDk0Q4XUtwvKOzrcd3iq9uis
   F81M1OIcR7lEewwcLp7tuNNkM3uNna3F2JQFo97Vriy/Xl4/f1cf5VWzXyym7PH
   hhx4dbgYKAAA7"
   ALT="Larry">
```

You can see that the data for the image is encoded in [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  I believe you can also use this format to assign images in javascript and to use them in CSS.

Comment: @apphacker: Thanks, I've modified the answer to reflect this

Comment: Just because IE is broken, that doesn't necessarily mean there isn't an application for this (useful) technique.

Comment: data: URIs are limited to 32KB in IE8 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897(VS.85).aspx); IE9 raises the limit to 4GB (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/15/ie9-beta-minor-change-list.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible: [See here](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2397.html)

Comment: He asked about HTML not about a specific (broken) implementation.