# How to make a download button that saves the content of a string?

Tags: php, filestream

I have a PHP script that is producing an string that I want to download as a  file by clicking a button.

I know how to save the string in a file on the web-server and point on it with a link, but that is not what I want to do.

I want by clicking a button to stream a file to the user that contains the string.

UPDATE: What I am looking for is something very close to this :

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA">text file</a>
```

The Question that puts for me is how do I transform the $string into this base64 part and what is utf-16le ?? Can someone explain this a bit?

**UPDATE** actually some bad guys have felt into frustration that they are unable to answer and closed the topic. Without asking me. ome peple here take this a competition to gather points. But I went on and found the solution to my question.

You simple have to add download="file.txt"

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA" download="file.txt">text file</a>
```

In this way you download a file. not a stream.

have fun.

Comment: Please add parts of your code you already tried, so we can have something to work with.

Comment: You need to save it on your server and then make a download link...

Comment: Please tell us how to stream the file, because it is too board. If you mean have the file data embedded, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: Great, the answer of Mathew Flaschen is what I am meaning, But I do not understand this part : base64,//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA .  I also tested it. but how do I make the string into the base64,//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600807/does-html-allow-for-embedded-encoding-of-images-by-stream

Comment: I found this : base64_encode in php, is this it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a solution:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourfilename.ini"');

//output the contents the file should contain. For example:
echo "a=1\nb=2\nc=3";
?>
```

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371771/4687348)

Comment: He want to stream a file not text...

Comment: I wrote my answer based to his original post

Comment: You changed your original answer...

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to save the file on your server and then just use html like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/files/myfile.txt" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Of course that the link will be changed dynamically by some js or jQuery (don't know how to do it? Go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/179717)

I'd send a respond from the php file that will contain the file name or path...

Also look at this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793756