# How to retrieve files from (jquery) Asp.Net webApi, authorized with Asp.Net Identity

Tags: javascript, jquery, png, asp.net-identity

Maybe there is a really simple solution... But lot of threads I looked at did not solve my issue... I will try to be as clear as possible.

On a Asp.Net WebApi project there is "DownloadController" which is currently looking like:

```
private HttpResponseMessage CreateFileResponse(string fileName, string originalName, List<string> allowedMimes)
    {
        // see if file exists
        if (!_FileProvider.Exists(fileName))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        // retrieve mimeType
        string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
        if (!allowedMimes.Contains(mimeType))
        {
            mimeType = _generalMimeType;
        }

        // open the file
        FileStream fileStream = _FileProvider.Open(fileName);

        // create the response
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = _FileProvider.GetLength(fileName);

        // if the mimetype is not allowed, download as attachment
        if (mimeType == _generalMimeType)
        {
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = originalName;
        }

        return response;
    }

    //for understanding the above
    public DownloadController()
    {
        _FileProvider = new FileProvider();
    }

    public interface IFileProvider
    {
        bool Exists(string name);
        FileStream Open(string name);
        long GetLength(string name);
    }
```

This piece of code worked perfectly when a simple HTTP GET (just an url in the browser) is done to a certain route on the controller.

```
    [Route("Download/Document/{documentid}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetDocument(Guid documentid)
    {
       -
       -
       -
       -
   return this.CreateFileResponse(fileName, document.filename, allowedMimes);    
    }
```

But now all controllers all authorized with the [Authorize] field of asp.net Identity. All requests now need a Authorization field with a token (Bearer "token") in there header. Now almost all requests are done with jquery where you can simply add a header field. But for downloading files this was not done. Using jquery with a token header on the DownloadController will give a response though:

> �PNG ↵↵ IHDR� ��sRGB���gAMA���a   pHYs���o........

Also fiddler and Postman are capable of showing the real image when I make a request with a token. (don't know for pdf files or other files)

But setting this data with certain javascript solutions I tried on stackoverflow won't work.... The image keeps broken.. Can somebody help me with a solution to set this data from javascript?:). Or an other solution of course.

Intercepted response from Fiddler:
[image: Intercepted response from Fiddler]

Comment: Are you trying to somehow render the response from your api in your html code? and is the response a stream of bytes?

Comment: @Pushpendra Yes, maybe a bit long story. But just wanted to be clear...

Answer (score 0):

There are tools such as [groupdocs](http://www.groupdocs.com) which converts the stream into an htmlresponse, images, native which you can use to render in your html code. You can probably do this in your api call befor sending the response  as stream of bytes. [groupdocs-library](http://groupdocs.com/dot-net/document-viewer-library)

Comment: Looks pretty nice. But I think it has to be possible without going for such a paid solution.

Comment: There is 1 way which I know is used for base64 encoding. This link should help you can try putting your stream in data or src attribute of img. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600807/does-html-allow-for-embedded-encoding-of-images-by-stream